# Save value of checkboxlist to db in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a yii2 form which contain a checkbox list items which i made like this:

```
<?php $CheckList = ["users" => 'Users', "attendance" => 'Attendance', "leave" => 'Leave', "payroll" => 'Payroll'];?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'MenuID')->checkboxList($CheckList,['separator'=>'<br/>']) ?>
```

Now what i need is to save the values in the database column as a comma separated value.

I tried to modify the create function in my controller in this way:

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Role();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {


        if ($model->MenuID != " ") {
           $model->MenuID = implode(",", $model->MenuID);                
        }
         $model->save();             
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->RoleID]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

But the values are not being saved in the database

Comment: Hi, try to use the PHP function serialize() to convert arrays to strings. $array =implode(",", $model->MenuID); $model->MenuID = serialize($array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your model `rules()`.

When you call `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());` the framework call method `setAttributes()` with param `$safeOnly = true`. This method with param $safe = true check if attributes are safe or not according to the rules of model. If you haven't any rules on the model all attributes are considered unsafe so your model is not populated.

**Add rules() on your model and your code works**

```
class Role extends yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['MenuID', 'your-validation-rule'],
        ];
    }

   ...
```

**Some additional info**

N.B. If you do not specify scenario in the rules the default scenario is `'default'` and if during instantiate of model object you set scenario to another didn't work. My example:

You have the same rules as I wrote before and you run this code

```
...
$model = new Role(['scenario' => 'insert']);

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
...
```

model is empty after load becouse any rules is founded in `'insert'` scenario and your problem is back. So if you want a rule that work only in particular scenario you must add `'on'` rules definition. Like this:

```
...
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['MenuID', 'your-validation-rule', 'on' => 'insert'],
    ];
}
...
```

For more example and explanations visit:

- [Declaring Rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#declaring-rules)
- [load()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail)
- [setAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#setAttributes()-detail)
- [safeAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#safeAttributes()-detail)